# Quadrics tangent to lines

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, projective-geometry, enumerative-geometry, schubert-calculus

I think that the following must be a basic question in enumerative geometry.

Take a line $L\subset\mathbb{P}^3$. The quadric surfaces in $\mathbb{P}^3$ that are tangent to $L$ are parametrized by a hypersurface $T$ of degree two in the $\mathbb{P}^9$ parametrizing all the quadrics modulo scalar. Therefore, the number of quadric surfaces tangent to nine general lines should be $2^9 = 512$.

Is this the right number of perhaps the nine hypersurfaces do no intersect transversally?

Thank you very much.

Comment: See H. Schubert (1879) p. 105 $\nu^9=92.$ Or [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2010.10879.pdf).

Comment: The hypersurfaces $T$ certainly do *not* intersect transversally, since each of  them is  singular along a $\Bbb{P}^6$ (parameterizing those quadrics which contain the given line).

Comment: You can find a modern presentation of the Schubert result in I. Vainsencher, *Schubert Calculus for Complete Quadrics*, in *Enumerative Geometry and Classical Algebraic Geometry*, Birkhäuser PM 24 (1982).